# How to add the same child View controllers to a parent view controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have two `UIViews` in a parent view (a `xib`).
I want to show in these two views **different instances** of the **same** View Controller.

I know how I can do it if I have just one view:

```
    [self addChildViewController:MyChildController];
    [self.myUIVIew addSubview:myChildView];
```

But how does it work if I want to have two of these ? (a comparison of views with different data for example).

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Obviously 

     `[self addChildViewController:MyChildControllerA];
    [self.myUIVIewA addSubview:myChildViewA];

 [self addChildViewController:MyChildControllerB];
    [self.myUIVIewB addSubview:myChildViewB];`

would fail because how would the framework know which controller should it use for which view if the controllers are of the same class ?

Comment: No, it won't. Keep a reference to both your view controllers from the parent and use them as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work. Framework uses instances, not a class. So two instances of the same class are different beings.